# Several alias without ejecting in React?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I have a React project that I created using CRA. Now, I would like to use several aliases in my project and so far the solutions I have found only allows me to specify no more than one folder (src e.g.). What is the most professional way to use more than one alias without ejecting the app? I know the best would be to eject but I am not sure I am ready.

Comment: maybe you need module babel-plugin-module-resolver, for many aliases, but i 'dnt know if your project has multiple external dependences

Comment: Thank you Soleil. However, that would only be configurable if I eject from CRA(Create React App) and I take full ownership of the webpack configuration, is that right?

Answer (score 1):

You may use

> yarn add react-app-rewired
>
> npm install react-app-rewired --save-dev

Allows you using aliases without ejecting.

Comment: Thanks but I read somewhere that the author mentioned he did not want to support future versions of CRA. Do you know anything about this?

Answer (score 1):

See this [github thread](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6953) about this issue.

You can see plenty of other people have requested this as a feature.

My opinion is that adding [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired) and [customize-cra](https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra) is the simplest solution without ejecting.

```
//config-overrides.js
const {
    override,
    addWebpackAlias,
  } = require("customize-cra");

const path = require('path'); 

module.exports = override( 
    addWebpackAlias({
        react: path.resolve('./node_modules/react')
    })
)
```

Comment: Do you know if there are plans to support future versions of CRA? Because I read somewhere that the author of react-app-rewired or customize-cra I do not remember which one exactly, mentioned that he did not want to support future releases anymore.

Comment: @JavierGuzman you can see that the referenced issue is open and has a fair bit of support. That's all I know.

Comment: Thanks! I think I will wait to see if the CRA developers add this feature... I would not like to add react-app-rewired or customize-cra just for aliases...